# Is it possible to do load testing of java swing application with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, java-gui

I need to perform load testing of java swing application. So there should be imitation of simultaneous actions on N instances of this application.

Is it possible to do it with [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter)?

I have doubts because of this statement in [Jmeter introduction](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/intro.html):

> please note that JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level.

Does `it works at protocol level` means that it will not work with swing app as a common functional testing tool e.g. UFT?

Or should load testing be like:

1. Define requests that are sent from application to server (with e.g. JMeter Proxy Recorder, but application uses `t3` protocol of weblogic server so guess it is not applicable here)
2. Set up Jmeter to send this requests?

Comment: http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Using-JMeter-with-a-Java-Swing-Application-td534253.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802229/jmeter-with-java-swing-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901988/using-jmeter-for-load-testing-of-a-standalone-java-application

Answer (score 10):

From Apache JMeter's website we get this,

> Ability to load and performance test many different server/protocol
>   types:
>
> ```
> Web - HTTP, HTTPS
> SOAP / REST
> FTP
> Database via JDBC
> LDAP
> Message-oriented middleware (MOM) via JMS
> Mail - SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)
> Native commands or shell scripts
> TCP
> ```

So I'm guessing you can't use it to load test Swing Application.

BUT

If your application makes HTTP(s) requests to a remote server, you can get help from your development team to collect all such requests and then use JMeter to generate load for those requests!

Answer (score 2):

JMeter doesn't mimic any UI actions so you won't be able to interact with Swing UI (at least not more than in 1 thread) so in fact you have 2 options:

1. T3 protocol is just a subset of [Java RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) protocol which in its turn using [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) transport.So if you need to "record and replay" the T3 network activity you could use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [JMeter's TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler). Also as far as I recall [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) tool comes with TCP proxy so you can consider changing the load testing tool if you decide to go the "record-and-replay" way.
2. A "smarter" approach would be replicating your desktop application functionality using [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) and either:

   - your application librarie(s) (if you drop it (them) to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to access your application API from JSR223 Test Elements
   - WebLogic T3 standalong client library, see [Developing a WebLogic Thin T3 Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT380) for more details.